# Uploading an image using the timymce editor returns a 405 error

Tags: spring-boot, tinymce, vuejs3

My environment is backend and spring boot frontend is vue3. When I try to upload an image using tinyMce editor, I can see a 405 error in the console window. Is this a bug in the editor? Or is there something I don't know?

I want to use automatic_uploads to save the picture file to the server in the form of a file rather than a blob. It has been confirmed that it is stored in blob format.

vue3 is running on port 8081 and spring boot is running on port 8080. vue and spring are communicating using a proxy.

vue3 file.

```js
<template>
    <div class="m-2">
        <table class=" border w-full border">
            <tr class="border">
                <th class="w-28 border">제목</th>
                <td class="border" colspan="2"><input type="text" class="w-full" v-model="title"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border">
                <th class="border">홈화면</th>
                <td class="border">
                    <editor
                    api-key="no-api-key"
                    :plugins="myPlugins" :toolbar="myToolbar" :init="myInit"
                    v-model="summary"
                    />
                </td>
                <td class="border w-20">
                    <input type="file" class="w-20 file" name="file" value="" accept="image/jpeg" @change="insertFile">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border">
                <th class="border">본문</th>
                <td class="border" colspan="2">
                    <editor
                      api-key="no-api-key"
                      :plugins="myPlugins" :toolbar="myToolbar" :init="myInit"
                      v-model="content"
                    /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="text-right gap-2">
            <button class="h-8 border w-16 mr-2 rounded-md bg-gray-300" @click="$router.push(`/contract/notice/contractNotice/${currentPage}`)">목록으로</button>
            <button class="h-8 border w-16 rounded-md bg-blue-300" @click="submitNotice">작성하기</button>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import router from '@/router'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

export default {
    name: 'CreateNoticeView',
    components: { editor: Editor },
    data () {
        return {
            isClick: false,
            compCode: [],
            myPlugins: 'image',
            myToolbar: 'fontfamily fontsize | bold italic underline | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | image | undo redo',
            myInit: {
                height: 410,
                menubar: false,
                resize: false,
                skin: 'outside',
                automatic_uploads: true,
                images_upload_url: '/api/notice/uploadFile',
                images_reuse_filename: true,
                // images_upload_url: "postAcceptor.php",
                images_upload_base_path: '',
                images_upload_credentials: true
                // images_upload_handler: this.exampleImageUploadHandler
            },

            title: '',
            summary: '',
            content: '',
            seq: '',
            numseq: '',
            currentPage: useRoute().params.currentPage,

            noticeRes: [],

            files_name: []
        }
    },
    methods: {

        insertFile (e) {
            const formData = new FormData()
            for (const file of e.target.files) {
                formData.append('file', file)
            }
            axios.post('/api/notice/uploadFile', formData, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
                .then((res) => {
                    this.files_name = res.data
                })
        },

        axios.post('/api/notice/submitNotice', {
            params: {
              title: this.title,
              summary: this.summary,
              content: this.content,
              seq: this.seq,
              numseq: this.numseq,
              compcode: this.compCode,
              imgname: this.files_name
            }
            }).then((res) => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    this.noticeRes = res.data
                    alert('글이 등록되었습니다.')
                    router.push(`/contract/notice/contractNotice/${this.currentPage}`)
                }
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

java method

```java
@PostMapping("/api/notice/uploadFile")
public JSONObject uploadFile(MultipartFile file) {

    String root_path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/frontend/src/assets/images/notice/";
    String fileName = null;
    String realName = null;
    String milName = null;
    String saveName =null;
    // 파일이 있으면 업로드
    if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {

        fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        String fileExt = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1,
                fileName.length());
        String fil11 = fileName.substring(0,fileName.indexOf("."));

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        long milliSecond = System.currentTimeMillis();
        milName = String.valueOf(milliSecond).substring(10, 13);

        realName = fil11 + "."+ fileExt;
        saveName = (sdf.format(new java.util.Date()) + milName  ) + "."+fileExt;
        File ckfile = new File(root_path + saveName);

        int i = 0;
        while (ckfile.exists()) {
            i++;
            saveName = ( (sdf.format(new java.util.Date()) + milName) ) + i  + "."+fileExt;
            ckfile = new File(root_path + saveName);
        }

        // upload 가능한 파일 타입 지정
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

            File outFile = new File(root_path + saveName);

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    outFile);
            fileOutputStream.write(bytes);
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //
        }
    } else {
        saveName = "not";
    }
    String path = "img/notice/";

    String returnFilepath = path + saveName;

    Map<String, String> resMap = new HashMap<>();

    resMap.put("location", returnFilepath);
    JSONObject resJson = new JSONObject(resMap);
    this.resJson = resJson;
    return resJson;
}
```

```
I hope this isn't a bug in tinyMce.
```

Answer (score 0):

For local development how does the Vue know that Java runs on port 8081?

If you don't specify the port number it will use the pages his own port which is 8080 (Vue and that will most likely give the 405 I think).

Can you try to change the upload URl to `http://localhost:8081/api/notice/uploadFile` and try it again?